# How can I get the objects from this model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm trying to create an address model/views/... that works and I got the model working, but I'm trying to access the data it contains and it's not working. Here is the model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    nick_name = models.CharField('Nick name', max_length=30, blank=True, default='')
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')
    # Address = models.ForeignKey('Address', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    # If we don't have this, it's going to say profile object only
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
        #return f'{self.user.username}'  # it's going to print username Profile

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super().save(*args, **kwargs)

            img = Image.open(self.image.path)

            if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
                output_size = (300, 300)
                img.thumbnail(output_size)
                img.save(self.image.path)


class Address(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(Profile, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=60, default="Miami")
    state = models.CharField(max_length=30, default="Florida")
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=5, default="33165")
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Address'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I'm trying to access all the addresses that a user can have. I tried:

```
# TESTS
allAddresses = Address.objects.all()
print(allAddresses)
```

and for the address objects it gives me: `<QuerySet [<Address: Elizabeth>, <Address: Work>]>`

But if I try to filter it by user, like this:

```
allAddresses = Address.objects.all().filter(users='arturo')
print(allAddresses)
```

it gives me an error: `invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'arturo'`

Could someone lead me on the way to get all the addresses of the logged in user please?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filter constraint `users` refers to the ID of the intermediate many-to-many table, hence the error. You should specify the related fields in full instead, where `user` refers to the `Profile.user` field, and `username` refers to the `User.username` field:

```
allAddresses = Address.objects.all().filter(users__user__username='arturo')
```

Comment: Excellent! That worked, thanks very much, where could I refer in the doc to know about the whole path? I was looking at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/instances/#auto-incrementing-primary-keys but I couldn't find it

Comment: Glad to be of help. Many-to-many fields can be looked up just like regular foreign key fields. You can refer to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/ (in the "Many-to-many relationships can be queried using lookups across relationships" section) for more details.